# How to measure performance of a pretrained HuggingFace language model?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am pretraining a `GPT2LMHeadModel` using `Trainer` as follows:

```py
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=str(project_root / 'models/bn-gpt2/'),
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=1,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
    fp16=True,
    optim="adafactor",
    eval_steps=400,
    save_steps=800,
    warmup_steps=500,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=tokenized_dataset['train'],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_dataset['test'],
)

trainer.train()
```

I want to measure the performance of my pre-trained model using perplexity or accuracy metrics during and after training. I have found some ways to measure these for individual sentences, but I cannot find a way to do this for the complete model. My goal is to create a next word prediction model for my native language using GPT2 training from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly then [this tutorial](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/perplexity#example-calculating-perplexity-with-gpt2-in-transformers) shows how to calculate perplexity for the entire test set. If I see it correctly they use the entire test corpus as one string connected by linebreaks, which might have to do with the fact that perplexity uses a sliding window which uses the text that came previous in the corpus. I personally did not calculate perplexity for a model yet and am not an expert at this. In any case you could average the sentence score into a corpus score, although there might be issues with the logic of how that metric works as well as the weighting since sentences can have a different number of words, see [this explaination](https://towardsdatascience.com/perplexity-in-language-models-87a196019a94).

Also I'm not sure if you are already aware of this but there is also a [pretrained GPT-2 model](https://huggingface.co/flax-community/gpt2-bengali) available for Bengali on huggingface.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to compute the perplexity score: non-overlapping and sliding window. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.15832.pdf) describes the details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).